# React router default route not working with nested structure

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have following code:

`layOut.js`

```
...
<Switch>
  <Route path="/app" component={AppLayout} />
</Switch>
...
```

`appLayout.js`

```
...
<Route path="/app/user/change-password" exact component={ChangePassword} />
<Can role="ADMIN">
  <Route path="/app/user/billing" exact component={Billing} />
</Can>
<Route component={NotFound} />
...
```

I was expecting the `NotFound` component to display when the route is not matching to the mentioned one(eg `/app/awd`), but instead, `NotFound` component is getting rendered in all the pages.

Comment: try adding `path="*"` at `<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />`

Comment: That also doesn't work, it still renders with other routes. Tried `path="*"`, `path="/app/*"` with & without `exact`

Comment: or in `layOut.js`, instead of doing `<Route path="/app" component={AppLayout} />`, just do `<AppLayout />`. Try see how it does.

Comment: Nope, its still the same.

Comment: Btw, `Can` is a self created `component` on your part right? (in `appLayout.js`)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed `Can` component in `appLayout.js` is a `protected` component created by yourself beyond this point.

From my experienced, having more than one dedicated `parent` `path` (Eg: `/app` or `/app2`) and thinking each of these `path` need their own `Not Found` path actually will not work and it will always render the `Not Found` component/page.

So in order to make this work, you just need to move your `Not Found` `route` in the `layOut.js`. Basically where `Switch` happen. Just once.

- `layOut.js`:-

```
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <AppLayout />
        <Route path="*" component={() => "Not Found"} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

- `appLayout.js`:-

```
const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/app/user/change-password"
        component={ChangePassword}
      />
      <Can role="ADMIN">
        <Route exact path="/app/user/billing" component={Billing} />
      </Can>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppLayout;
```